# When toggle speaker on/off in a voip call, mic is not working anymore in IOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, voip, avaudiosession

I have a VoIP app and while taking a call, when the user turns on speaker mode the other side hears the user sound like a robot sound.

and when the user turned off speaker mode to back normal, the other side don't hear anything from the user.

Here's the code which is responsible for switching audio ports

```
- (void)setAudioOutputSpeaker:(BOOL)enabled
{
    AVAudioSession *session =   [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error;
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
    if (enabled) // Enable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
    }
    else // Disable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
    }
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}
```

The code is working fine and everything is great on IOS 9 and before, the problem happens in IOS 10 only

---

### update 1

when listing the input datasources using

```
[AVAudioSession inputDataSources];
```

I got list for front,back,bottom microphones while the app isn't started the call yet and audio category is `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`

but when starting a call and turning the category into `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` the aboves method for input datasources returns `nil`

Comment: are you using CallKit? and which sip stack are you using?

Comment: @HashmatKhalil No Callkit, I'm managing all in my own and have my own sound manager class. Also I'm using our own sip stack and it's a private one related to Orange.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil what I can't understand is, everything is working fine except this speaker issue and only on IOS 10.

Comment: OIC. On iOS 10 apps get notified through callkit when to configure audio session and when to start & stop audio streams. I've still some issues with gsm call while connecting or disconnecting where pjsip tries start audio on its own but ends up with no audio stream. take a look at slide 141 http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/230b83wfxc7m69dm90q/230/230_enhancing_voip_apps_with_callkit.pdf

Comment: does setting active gives an error? are you listening for audio interruption and route changes?